# xdocument save adding extra characters

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm using XDocument to load and save a config file. Most of the time it works correctly, but there are cases (seemingly random) where it appends extra information after the last tag. Here's a gist of what's happening.

Config file pre-run:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<local>
</local>
```

code:

```
XDocument config = new XDocument();
config = XDocument.Load(new FileStream(@"c:\foo.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
XElement fileEle = config.Root.Element("files");
XElement statsEle = new XElement("stats");
statsEle.Add(new XElement("one", "two"));
statsEle.Add(new XElement("three", "four"));
.
.
.
fileEle.Add(statsEle);
config.Save(new FileStream(@"c:\foo.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), SaveOptions.None);
```

config file post-run:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<local>
    <files>
        <one>two</one>
        <three>four</three>
    </files>
</local>s>
</local>
```

Any suggestions? No idea why the extra characters are being added. Sometimes it's the extra tag, sometimes it's different characters and sometimes it works correctly. I've tried loading/saving using different methods (XMLReader, etc.), adding XML tags different ways.. after X runs they all produce the same error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two `FileStream`'s open for the same file concurrently... one for reading `foo.xml`, and one for overwriting it.  That seems very problematic.

I'd recommend:

- Disposing of the read `FileStream` as soon as your `XmlDocument` is loaded:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\foo.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    config.Load(fs);
}
```

- Use `FileMode.Truncate` in your write `FileStream` so that the file is truncated to 0 bytes before you start writing to it.

Comment: Good catch. The `Xdocument.Load(new FileStream)...))` leaves a dangling File open.

Comment: @Andrew good catch. I was still getting errors after closing the filestreams, but it seems that opening with truncate fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Eckstein: If this solution works, then using `XDocument.Load` and `config.Save(filename)` should work too.

Comment: That's what I figured.. seems should be same implementation under the hood.

Comment: After some more testing Load and Save worked. DLL may have been out of date.. Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that something's *actually* overwriting (but not truncating) the file with *fewer* tags - and what you're seeing is the remains of a larger XML file.

I've never seen LINQ to XML do anything like this itself.

Can you run the same tests which always fail, but in a mode where each iteration writes to a *new* file instead of overwriting the old one?

Is there any reason you're loading directly from `FileStreams` (which are never being closed, as another answer points out) instead of just using `XDocument.Load(filename)`, `XDocument.Save(filename)`?

Comment: that's exactly right.  I battled with this for some time a while back

Comment: still experienced with .Save, but writing to a new file fixed the problem. Seems like a flawed design that the original file isn't deleted, or something similar, prior to writing. Or maybe I just have bad luck :) Thanks!

Comment: @Eckstein: Are you sure you don't have multiple threads doing this? Is this writing to a network share, or just a local drive?

Comment: It's a multi-threaded application, but no more than one thread is ever accessing the config file. Writing to a local drive.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before... just can't think how to resolve it.  I think it's got something to do with the way you are saving. You need to make sure you overwrite everything. I can't remember if it's the filemode or options... or another setting